# USB connection type pop-up not showing

Tags: settings, usb, connection-issues, windows, android-auto

The main reason I am loyal to Android is it was always easy to plug my phone into my Windows PC and transfer files.  Recently, my phone is not recognized by my PC.  It doesn't even give me the menu on my phone to pick what to do when connected (charge, transfer files, etc.). In the settings on my phone, everything is greyed out.

[image]

I also think this is causing Android Auto not to work in my car.  Others have tested their phones and can connect to the radio instantly. I have searched the settings and developer options and can not find which setting is incorrect.

Comment: Was there a change (e.g. a software update) or something else you remember that has changed which could be the reason that the connection suddenly does no longer work? The other possible reason is a hardware problem, USB cables can get defect or USB socket can get (partially) loose so that the data connection fails.

Comment: It's also worth rebooting the phone in case it's just confused.

Comment: Could you mention the device model, or at least the USB type? Have you confirmed that the USB cable is also a data cable, not a charging-only cable?

Comment: motorola one 5G UW ace, phone is USB c and the PC /car is USB a